# What is the difference between getSigners and getNamedAccounts?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am finding it difficult to understand difference between these two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getSigners` and `getNamedAccounts` are both used for the same purpose, getting public key for accounts.

Since you asked for `getNamedAccounts` I assume you are developing on a hardhat environment because it is used to retrieve accounts manually from the attribute `namedAccounts` defined whithin `hardhat.config.js` and it is an exclusive feature with the plugin `hardhat-deploy`.

In the other hand a signer in ethers.js is an object that represents an Ethereum account. `getSigners` helps getting a list of the accounts in the node we're connected to, which is probably the Hardhat Network.

Comment: If I write getNamedAccounts instead of getSigners in my code, the code won't run. Here is my code [link](https://gist.github.com/ameeetgaikwad/b88235b1268d45e53d76574e34c255fc)

Comment: `getNamedAccounts` configurations should be included in `hardhat.config.js`, u should have a similar code snippet.
```json
module.exports = {
...
      namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> If I write getNamedAccounts instead of getSigners in my code, the code won't run ?

Because you are using named accounts. That's why `getNamedaccounts` results in an error.
Check your `hardhat.config`, looking from gist you may have a Named account variable as deployer.

Comment: Yeah right, i did!

Comment: ```javascript
namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
    user: {
      default: 0,
    },
  },
```